# Framer Motion Animate Presence is not working with new NextJS App Router's Intercepting Routes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion, next.js13

I'm trying to create a modal using intercepting routes as shown in this [example](https://github.com/vercel-labs/nextgram) on NextJS docs. I'm using framer motion to implement modal animation but Animate Presence is not working in this case.

My `page.tsx` file inside `app/(features)/@loginModal/(.)login/page.tsx`

```
import Modal from "@General/Modal";
import Login from "@Auth/Login";

export default function NavbarLogin() {
    return (
        <Modal>
            <Login />
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

My `layout.tsx` file inside `app/(features)/layout.tsx`

```
"use client";

import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import Navbar from "@Navbar/Navbar";
import Guard from "@Auth/Guard";

export default function MainLayout({
    children,
    loginModal,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    loginModal: React.ReactNode;
}) {
    console.log(loginModal);
    return (
        <Guard>
            <main>
                <Navbar />
                <div className="pt-20">
                    {children}
                    <AnimatePresence>{loginModal}</AnimatePresence>
                </div>
            </main>
        </Guard>
    );
}
```

I tried changing the `AnimatePresence` tag to different locations like the `app/layout.tsx`, `app/(auth)/layout.tsx`, `app/(auth)/login/page.tsx` etc.. in my code but it didn't work.

EDIT:
Found this issue on github https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/1850 https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49279 but none of the workarounds mentioned in this is working in the current version. Does anyone know how to fix this in latest version?

Answer (score 1):

When using Animate Presence, the framer components are required to have the entry, exit, and key props.

```
<AnimatePresence>
                {open && (
                    <motion.div
                        key='box'
                        initial={{ opacity: 0, y: '-100%' }}
                        exit={{ opacity: 0, y: '-100%' }}
                        animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
                        transition={{ duration: 0.5, ease: 'easeOut' }}
                        className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-8 md:hidden bg-primary'
                    >
                        ...component related work here
                    </motion.div>
                )}
            </AnimatePresence>
```

The `key` prop is important because it's needed by Framer to identify which component to add the animations to.

Comment: This perfectly does the trick ! thank you @kunalkeshan